# Why does Vader have different speech patterns than Anakin Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, anakin-skywalker

Darth Vader sounds formal and euridite, whereas Anakin's speech patterns come off as "casual" in comparison to Vader's "antiquated diction," as Tarkin described it in a canon novel.

Why does Vader sound like that?

Comment: Anakin was young, full of hormones and emotions. Hormones were... burned out after the fight with Obi Wan and then he had to learn to control his emotions, his anger, in order to channel it to more powerful Force moves.

Comment: Folks with breathing problems choose their words more carefully

Comment: Why does he have completely different accents when played by Lloyd, Christiansen, and Shaw?

Comment: Why would expect that he wouldn't?

Comment: he installed the dark brooding English language pack into his suit. ($9.99 on EA store)

Comment: @Max Is that really how the suit works? Doesn't the vocoder just repeat what he says with his own mouth?

Comment: Because James Earl Jones was a veteran actor with superb delivery which he had developed over years of honing his acting craft - and Hayden Christiansen wasn't.

Comment: He might have just [gone through puberty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSm9DDxQv8E)

Comment: @Max $9.99? _Only_? Are you sure that's from EA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Darth Vader purposely modify his voice?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123989/did-darth-vader-purposely-modify-his-voice)

Comment: Note down somewhere: Vader killed Anakin. They aren't same.

Answer (score 2):

### Different actors, different speech patterns

James Earl Jones was a veteran actor with superb delivery which he had developed over years of honing his acting craft - and Hayden Christiansen wasn't.

Comment: I think the question was looking for an *in-universe* answer, since this out-of-universe one is quite obvious.

Comment: @Randal'Thor If the character sounds a certain way, how is that in universe?  Be it books on tape or on film, it is out of universe actors who are saying the words.  The question cites no description from any text nor script direction.  Thus one  must answer what was asked.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm also looking for an in- universe explanation. Both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sith lords insist on good diction.

Even the most unruly apprentice can be shocked and choked into line I'm sure.

The Jedi probably insist also, but without any real punishment or reward system how could they hope to deal with a brat like Ani